# Show that the following equality involving the Mobius function holds.

Tags: number-theory

Show that $\displaystyle \sum_{d^2 | n} \mu (d) = |\mu (n)|$. where $\mu$ is the Mobius function.

I am not sure on how to continue this problem. My starting point is to show that if $n = n_1^2 n_2$ then $d^2 | n \Leftrightarrow d| n_1$ ($n _2$ is square-free). If this is correct, how would I conclude?

Comment: This is the same as showing $\sum_{d|n}\mu(d) = 0$ whenever $n>1$. Since $\mu(n)$ is a (partially) multiplicative function, If $n = p_1^{r_1} \cdots p_m^{r_m}$, $\sum_{d|n}\mu(d) = \sum_{d|p_1^{r_1}} \mu(d) \cdots \sum_{d|p_m^{r_m}}\mu(d)$.

Comment: There are two cases to consider here. In the first case, suppose that $n$ is square free. In the second, suppose that $n$ has $k$ distinct prime divisors with exponent 2 or greater and use the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Your starting point is correct, but you have to show it. You may continue like this: $$\sum_{d^2 | n} \mu (d)=\sum_{d | n_1} \mu (d)=
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $n_1=1$} \\
0, & \text{if $n_1>1$}
\end{cases}
$$
using the most important [property of the Möbius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function). So the sum is $1$ if $n$ is squarefree, and $0$ otherwise, exactly as $|\mu(n)|$.